# No error, but the result is Undefined. Why does this happen in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have 2 identical functions. But they return 2 different things..

```
function fun1()
{
  return {
      obj: "hello"
  };
}

function fun2()
{
  return
  {
      obj: "World..!"
  };
}
```

So, when i add something to print out the functions,

```
console.log("fun1 returns:");
console.log(fun1());
console.log("fun2 returns:");
console.log(fun2());
```

My O/p is:

```
fun1 returns:
Object {obj: "hello"}
fun2 returns:
undefined
```

Why does this happen. Is this a structural mistake?? How do i get to make the 2nd function print out identical o/p??

Comment: When you break out the `{` in `fun2` onto a different line, there is an automatic `;` added after your `return` statement, so it really evaluates out to: `function fun2() { return; }`

Answer (score 0):

Because javascript inserts a `;` right after `return` in the `func2` function.